# Node.js and Wavesurfer.js

Tags: node.js, wavesurfer.js

Up to this point in my studies, I have been able to serve files to my dynamic web pages using Node.js and Express as follows.

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

and then linking to files in the public folder.

The Wavesurfer.js documentation stated that a file has to be loaded from a url

> Load an audio file from a URL:

```
wavesurfer.load('example/media/demo.wav');
```

I'm not to sure I understand what this mean. or how to link a file to wavesurfer.js using node.js

**Edit:**

I found this from the link [Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.” error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Node.js
Alternatively, if you demand a more responsive setup and already use nodejs...

1. Install `http-server` by typing `npm install -g http-server`
2. Change into your working directory, where your `some.html` lives
3. Start your http server by issuing `http-server -c-1`

This spins up a Node.js httpd which serves the files in your directory as static files accessible from `http://localhost:8080`

Can't I achieve the same using express?

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="waveform"></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple'
            });

            wavesurfer.load('/public/recordings/o.mp3');


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The errors I'm getting:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or
> created) after a user gesture on the page.
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/public/recordings/o.mp3' from
> origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
> are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Are you trying to use wavesurfer on the backend or the frontend?

Comment: frontend i suppose

Comment: In that case, you already have an Express server, so just put an audio file in the `public/` directory and you can then load it in frontend code as: `wavesurfer.load('/public/audio file.wav')`

Comment: that is the first thing that I tried but it didn't work

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Ok and when you say it didn't work, is there an error?

Comment: The first error actually gives a url at the end but I couldn't submit the question without removing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I think your problem is because you open the `.html` page in your browser locally (as a `file://`). Instead, try to load it from your Express server, something like `http://localhost:`***port***`/some file.html`

Comment: you are right :) I did that. However i'm still getting the following error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Comment: It started working once I removed the public folder and used everything after that, so instead of `wavesurfer.load('/public/recordings/o.mp3');` i used `wavesurfer.load('/recordings/o.mp3');`